# Unfounded segfault in a memory searcher function

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, segmentation-fault, undefined-behavior

My memory searcher function used to locate the occurrence of the string "initial" in memory.

```
volatile unsigned char* ptr;
size_t offset_address;
static char nm [8], idx;

for(ptr = ((volatile unsigned char* )&offset_address); idx <= sizeof("initial") - 1; ptr++)
{
    if(*ptr == *("initial" + idx))
        *(nm + idx) = *ptr, idx++;
    else idx = 0;
}
```

What is wrong with it to cause "Read Error in line `if(*ptr == *("initial" + idx))` access beyond authorized memory area" ? (Errors if I increment the pointer even only once, yet if I don't increment the pointer at all, no error occurs)

Comment: Can you give the actual error like word for word? this will help immensely.

Comment: This is the actual error and I think it is pretty much case-explanatory. Because it is returned from C89 interpreter and because Valgrind seems to be on the same side. Cannot think of more accurate debugging.

Comment: Oh forgot to mention that it is executed on a x86 bit system. This is a.. very complicated architecture.

Comment: Can you debug this by checking the size of the pointer before and after assigning the unsigned char, and check its contents? This would be valid debugging of the `for` loop.

Comment: I will, although, I am pretty sure the size of the pointer will be one and the same whatever I do.

Comment: The pointer size is 12.

Comment: Malina - when I debug your code I get the same error message, however I receive "Error reading characters from string". I'm using VS 2013 to debug. Is this because the ptr has no memory allocated for it to store the string?

Comment: `nm` stores the string, and it is statically allocated to hold 8 characters (9 with the nt). `ptr` is just a pointer to a valid memory.

Comment: Malina - This will be my last post but could you give the value of each variable I can't really go off of the error message given when I debug without having more information to test with. Thanks.

Comment: `nm` and `idx` are initially 0. `offset_address` seems to be optimized to be 0 as well, if it matters, size of `ptr` is always 12 and is not a null pointer after initialization. Little Endian x86 bit system.

Comment: where is the limit for ptr? seems you have no ending condition for the loop  if 'initial' is never found.

Answer (score 1):

There might be an infinite loop in your `for` loop, and then the `ptr` keeps growing up. Finally, trying to deference it by `*ptr` will cause error.

```
for(ptr = /*...*/; idx <= sizeof("initial") - 1; ptr++) <-- infinite loop if idx=0
{
    if(*ptr == *("initial" + idx))
        *(nm + idx) = *ptr, idx++;
    else idx = 0; <-- always goes here if no matching
}
```

Comment: The problem occurs even if I increment the pointer even only once, therefore the problem appears to be more complicated.

Comment: In some architecture, there might exist an unaligned memory access illegal, which require address alignment. So, maybe you could verify it on your env with simpler statement such as `tmp = *(ptr+1)` or `tmp = *("initial"+1)` to see which operation will cause read error.

Comment: Good idea Eric, yes this is a new PC I am taking advantage of.
It had initially installed Vista, then XP, now 7 on it. `char tmp = *("Hello World" + 1);` works fine, however, `char tmp = *("Hello World" + 12);` does not and it throws exactly the same error message.

Comment: Let's have a look. We will get 'e' with `char tmp = *("Hello World" + 1);`, but it could be out of bound with `char tmp = *("Hello World" + 12);` because 12 is beyond the length of the string. Then trying  to deference the memory located at `"Hello World"+12` will cause the mentioned error. Back to original program, if `ptr` points to the invalid/illegal memory address value, then `*ptr` will give the similar error just like that happened to `char tmp = *("Hello World" + 12);`. Sometimes, this kind of error seems to happen randomly util access some critical memory via `*ptr` .

Comment: Yes, this is my theory too.. I mean there is nothing else that could explain it otherwise. It somehow manages to store the data around unaccessible area, maybe at the end of its virtual memory. In that case, NAI may not cause any complications. However, it does. NAI results in the same error, expect for "beyond" has been replaced with "before" therefore it is literally surrounded by unaccessible memory. Might be protected from OS.. no idea.

Comment: Yes. And I tested your program under OS X now, even there is infinite loop it will run hundreds of times until the error message reported. In my test, the first time in loop `ptr = 0x7fff508adb58`, then it will run a few times, finally  when `ptr = 0x7fff508adfff`, deference it by `*ptr` will fail and give the error message. As you have known, deference an illegal pointer might not fail immediately until it destroyed the critical data region/stack layout etc. As to address alignment, I met some error before about memory write failure on ARM env(after cross compile )while it runs well on X86.

Comment: Yes that happens only if I dereference it. If I decide to print it as a string, it works. Hm.